# COUNT DISTINCT MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called "orders"

```
clientID |  order_status
client1  | pending  
client1  | shipped
client2  | pending  
client2  | complete 
client3  | complete  
client3  | shipped
client4  | pending  
client4  | pending 
client5  | shipped  
client5  | shipped 
client6  | complete  
client6  | complete
```

I want to select any clientID that has records with order_status of both "pending" and "shipped"

**This example should return only "client1"**

Here is my query:

```
SELECT clientID  
FROM orders  
WHERE order_status IN("pending", "shipped")  
GROUP BY clientID  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Which returns:

```
client1
client4
client5
```

I know I need to use **COUNT (DISTINCT order_status)** but this is a Microsoft Access Database and I'm not sure how to implement it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally handled by using a inline view in MSAccess.  The inline view gets you the distinct order_status by client and then you can count.

```
SELECT clientID
FROM (SELECT ClientID, order_status 
      FROM orders 
      WHERE order_status IN("pending", "shipped")  
      GROUP BY clientID, order_status) B
GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Or (because I don't like group by w/o aggregation)

```
SELECT clientID
FROM (SELECT Distinct ClientID, order_status 
      FROM orders 
      WHERE order_status IN("pending", "shipped")) B
GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Which your question

> select any clientID that has records with order_status of both
>   "pending" and "shipped"

I think the query statement should use and operator in where condition like that

```
SELECT clientID
FROM orders 
WHERE order_status = "pending" AND order_status = "shipped"
```

Comment: This would return no results because the order_status can only contain one value per record. "pending" and "shipped" are the order_status for two separate records